# Opposite of -Winline - how to warn on functions that were not marked inline but were inlined anyway

Tags: c, gcc, inline

I'm trying to cram a lot of code into a small microcontroller, while making it fast. I'm compiling with `-O3` and link time optimisation which is generally doing what I want, but I'm finding that in some cases GCC is inlining functions that I know would be a bad idea and it's really increasing the code size.

When I find those functions, I can mark them not to be inlined - that's fine. The problem is finding them...

So is there a way to see a report of which functions have been inlined? Even if it was just a warning that a function without the 'inline' keyword had been inlined - but even better would be a list of `function name, function size, times inlined, size increase/decrease`

Comment: It was for a different problem, but I have used `asm("/* function f */");`, in the body of function `f`, as a marker that I could trace in the generated assembly. If you find more than one instance, it means the function was inlined. The drawback is that the `asm` statement itself may prevent a function from being inlined that would otherwise have been, so it is not perfect.

Comment: I would try to compile with the `-Os` flag. In my experience, there is little performance difference between `-Os` and `-O3`; moreover, sometimes `-O3` generates *slower* code due to backfired optimizations. Alternatively, you could give `-finline-limit` a shot.

Comment: Thanks. I guess `-Os` still honours functions explicitly tagged as `inline`? When benchmarking I have found it's maybe 5% slower though. It'd just be nice to see functions GCC has inlined in case I forgot to inline something important.

Comment: I guess if I could print line numbers by the asm generated I could run it through a script to detect duplicates? There must be an easier way though.

Answer (score 1):

GCC 4.9 documents the option `-fopt-info-optimized-inline` which is supposed to report all successful inlines, but it doesn't seem to work... In none of my tests it reported anything.